# Duplicate nodes for everything in umbraco admin dashboard

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

Suddenly we have duplicate nodes of EVERYTHING on our admin dashboard, what gives?

I checked the DB, there are no duplicate published=1 nodes.
Using Umbraco 6.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by Deleting the "cache" folder which is the `App_Data` folder.
The site rebuilds this index. There must have been duplicates in the App_Data folder, clearing this folder solved the issue for me.